# “iter() returned non-iterator” for dynamically bound `next` method

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, python-2.x, python-internals

Why does this `next` method I dynamically bound to an instance of a class fail and return a non-iterator object?

```
from collections import Iterator
from collections import Iterable
from types import MethodType

def next(cls):
    if cls.start < cls.stop:
        cls.start += 1
        return cls.start
    else:
        raise StopIteration


class Foo(object):
    start, stop = 0, 5

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    setattr(foo, 'next', MethodType(next, foo, Foo))
    print hasattr(foo, "next")
    if isinstance(foo, Iterable):
        print "iterable"
    if isinstance(foo, Iterator):
        print "iterator"

    for i in foo:
        print i
```

Output:

```
iterable
True
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Foo'
```

It worked properly, when I did `setattr(Foo, 'next', classmethod(next))`.

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do?

Comment: I want to dynamically bind the next method to make it an iterator.

Comment: Special methods, which are usually `__double_underscored__` names, but also include `next` in Python 2 (it's renamed `__next__` in Python 3), must be defined on a class, not on an instance. You'd have a similar issue dynamically adding an `__add__` method, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in foo:
    print i
```

This is the code that failed, so let’s take a look at what happens internally there, diving into the source for some Python internals!

When `for i in foo` is compiled, the generated bytecode will contain the `GET_ITER` opcode which is responsible of converting `foo` into an iterable. `GET_ITER` causes a [`PyObject_GetIter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Python/ceval.c#L2797) call on the object which is the actual implementation that provides the iterable. So let’s take a look at [what it does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Objects/abstract.c#L3085):

```c
PyObject * PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *o)
{
    PyTypeObject *t = o->ob_type;
    getiterfunc f = NULL;
    if (PyType_HasFeature(t, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER))
        f = t->tp_iter;
    if (f == NULL) {
        if (PySequence_Check(o))
            return PySeqIter_New(o);
        return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
    }
    else {
        PyObject *res = (*f)(o);
        if (res != NULL && !PyIter_Check(res)) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                         "iter() returned non-iterator of type '%.100s'",
                         res->ob_type->tp_name);
            Py_DECREF(res);
            res = NULL;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

As you can see (if you understand some basic C at least), the underlying type is looked up from the object first (`o->ob_type`), and then its iter function is read (`t->tp_iter`).

Since you have implemented an `__iter__` function on the type, this function does exist, so we get to the `else` case in the code above, which runs the `iter` function on the object `o`. The result is non-null, but we still get the “returned non-iterator” message, so the `PyIter_Check(res)` appears to have failed. So let’s take a look at [what that does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Include/abstract.h#L637):

```c
#define PyIter_Check(obj) \
    (PyType_HasFeature((obj)->ob_type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER) && \
    (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != NULL && \
    (obj)->ob_type->tp_iternext != &_PyObject_NextNotImplemented)
```

So this one essentially checks if the *type* (`ob_type`) of the passed object has a non-null `next` method (`tp_iternext`) which does not happen to be the not-implemented next function.

Check closely where that check happens though: On the result’s **type**, not the result itself. The `foo` object does have a `next` function, but its type `Foo` does not have one.

```
setattr(foo, 'next', MethodType(next, foo, Foo))
```

… or more explicitly …

```
foo.next = next.__get__(foo, Foo)
```

… does only set the bound `next` method *on the instance* but not on the type itself. So the above C code will fail consuming it as an iterable.

If you were to set your `next` function on the *type* instead, it would work fine:

```
foo = Foo()
Foo.next = next

for i in foo:
    print i
```

This is the reason why your attempt with `classmethod` worked: You set the function on the *type* instead of its concrete instance.